# How can I extract all text between brackets in a PHP DocComment?

Tags: php, regex

Let's say my DocComment looks like this:

```
/** 
 *  [Test] 
 *  [AnotherTest]
 */
```

What I want to end up with is an array that contains "Test" and "AnotherTest"

I know how to retrieve the DocComment using Reflection, I'm just not sure how I can parse those values out cleanly. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the following regex should work:

```
/\[(.*?)\]/
```

Comment: Doing a preg_match on that regular expression gives me an array containing "[Test]" and "Test".

Comment: @TaylorOtwell: The regex works fine (tested). Are you sure you are using it correctly?

Comment: @TaylorOtwell: That is the intended behavior. First index is the entire expression match, and all subsequents are capture groups.

Comment: @simshaun: I just pasted it into a PHP preg_match function. Does anything need modification?